# Entity Framework saying invalid object name when table exists

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I've had to jump in to a complex project and am making unit tests for a particular repository in a WEB API service. The database CRUD is handled by the Entity Framework.

```
    private class IntegrationScope : AutoRollbackTransactionTestScope<DocumentRepository>
    {
        public IntegrationScope()
        {
            DependencyResolverMock = MockDependencyResolverFor<IResourceUrlBuilder, ResourceUrlBuilder>(new ResourceUrlBuilder());
            LoggingProviderMock = new Mock<ILoggingProvider>();

            // use real document micro service AutoMapper & Unity configuration
            AutoMapperConfig.RegisterMaps(Mapper.Configuration, DependencyResolverMock);
            UnityConfig.RegisterTypes(TestScopeContainer);

            //Set the DomainId
            TestId = Guid.NewGuid();

            TestDocument = BuildDocument(TestId);

            // get the real object
            DocumentStoreDbContext = TestScopeContainer.Resolve<IDocumentDbContext>();

            InstanceUnderTest = new DocumentRepository(DocumentStoreDbContext);
        }

        public static Web.Service.DocumentStore.Domain.Document BuildDocument(Guid documentId)
        {
            // Invoke GetBytes method.
            byte[] array = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Byte Repository Test");

            return Builder<Web.Service.DocumentStore.Domain.Document>
                .CreateNew()
                .With(t => t.Id = documentId)
                .With(t => t.Data = array)
                .Build();
        }
```

When it gets to the DocumentStoreDbContext line, there is no compilation error but i get a run-time error saying that the object name is invalid:

[image]

After doing some research this error appears to be because the database/table doesn't exist, however I can see that it does exist:

[image]

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: Had you checked that the table is correctly mapped in Entity model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

InnerException displays the table name as `DocumentStore.Documents`, but your SSMS screenshot shows `dbo.Documents`.

Could this be the cause?